# Floating div and flexible height

Tags: css-float, height, floating

Maybee this has been answered before, but can't find an real useful answer, so here goes:

I have this layout [layout test](http://jsfiddle.net/ecsJ8/2/), where I need the orange box to have the same height as the green, which will have dymanic content.

I'v tried different solutions, but not getting the right resultat. One solution was to have the orange and green box have:

```
padding-bottom: 500em;
margin: -500em;
```

and the parent `overflow: hidden;`

but the problem began with the red box bottom (floating on top of the purple) was cut off because of `overflow: hidden;`

Does anybody have an solution or maybe an idea? I prefer pure CSS, if possible.

The solution which works for me:

[New layout test](http://jsfiddle.net/ecsJ8/4/)

Comment: jQuery or JS will help you to detect the height of the div and later set that height for another

Comment: Orange and Green, are these going to have dynamic heights or can they be static?  Also, if you are dynamically generating a page with asp or php, you could just plug in a number from those.

Comment: Yes, sry fore that. Only the Green are going to have dynamic height, so the Orange bottom should always follow the Green bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with my own solution, link in question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i couldn't find a solution with pure CSS, but with this simple jquery you may have the desired result:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
var green = $('.col3').height();
var red = $('.col1').height();
    $('.col2').height(green - red + 15);
});
```

Comment: the +15 at the end is because the difference between the red and the green one is 15px

Comment: Good point, but used display table on left and right col, with table-cell inside. Last a div in left col, which works as bottom with height as difference between left and right col. Works and is pure CSS :) I'll post an example later, when I'm at my computer :)